# How to extract the characters that simultaneously exist in multiple columns and print the matched row in the new pd?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with multiple columns. I want to extract the characters that simultaneously exist in `from1` and `to1` columns, and print the corresponding matched rows in a new pd.

**Here is my data.**

```
classes = [('2.7.2.3', 'a primary alcohol','pyruvate'),
         ('2.7.1.3', 'a secondary alcohol','acetoacetyl-CoA'),
         ('3.1.1.3', 'a ketone','D-ribulose 5-phosphate'),
         ('3.1.2.3', '2,3-dioxo-L-gulonate','a primary alcohol'),
         ('2.7.2.3', 'L-iditol','D-ribulose 5-phosphate'),
         ('1.7.99.4', 'glycerol', 'keto-L-sorbose'),
         ('1.1.1.304', 'pyruvate', 'oxidized coenzyme F420-1'),
         ('2.7.4.3', 'D-ribulose 5-phosphate', 'a secondary alcohol')]   
labels = ['Ko_EC','from1', 'to1']
alls = pd.DataFrame.from_records(classes, columns=labels)
```

I tried the  `def`, as follows:

```
def aggregation(alls):
    netsum = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Ko_EC','from', 'to'])
    for val in alls['from1']:
        ll=alls.loc[alls['to1'].str.contains(val),:]
        
        new_row = {'Ko_EC':ll['Ko_EC'],
                   'from':ll['from1'],
                   'to':ll['to1']}
        netsum = netsum.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    return netsum
net_result = aggregation(alls)
net_result
```

Its partial results are:

```
        Ko_EC                                 from                                to
0   3 3.1.2.3               3 2,3-dioxo-L-gulonate               3 a primary alcohol
1   7 2.7.4.3             7 D-ribulose 5-phosphate             8 a secondary alcohol
2   Series([], Name: Ko_EC, dtype: object)..    Series([], Name: to1, dtype: object)
```

**The wanted results** are like below:

```
      Ko_EC                    from                        to
    2.7.2.3       a primary alcohol                  pyruvate
    2.7.1.3     a secondary alcohol           acetoacetyl-CoA
    3.1.2.3    2,3-dioxo-L-gulonate         a primary alcohol
    2.7.2.3                L-iditol    D-ribulose 5-phosphate
  1.1.1.304                pyruvate  oxidized coenzyme F420-1
    2.7.4.3  D-ribulose 5-phosphate       a secondary alcohol
```

in which the `2.7.2.3` and `3.1.2.3` rows were printed in a new pd because their  `a primary alcohol` simultaneously exists in `from1` and `to1` columns, and the `3.1.1.3` row was excluded because `a ketone` only exists in `from1` column, so does `D-ribulose 5-phosphate` in `to1` column.

In other words, **the unmatched rows in which the characters only exist `from1` or `to1` columns, will be filtered.**

Answer (score 0):

It is a stupid code but useful, hoping anyone could give more simple method.

```
from1 = alls['from1'].tolist()
to1 = alls['to1'].tolist()
con_exist1 = [x for x in from1 if x in to1]
con_exist2 = [y for y in to1 if y in from1]
con_exist = con_exist1 + con_exist2
targets = '|'.join(con_exist)
#targets

ll1 = alls.loc[alls['from1'].str.contains(targets),:]
ll2 = alls.loc[alls['to1'].str.contains(targets),:]
ll = pd.merge(ll1, ll2, how="outer")
ll
```

```
       Ko_EC                   from1                       to1
0    2.7.2.3       a primary alcohol                  pyruvate
1    2.7.1.3     a secondary alcohol           acetoacetyl-CoA
2  1.1.1.304                pyruvate  oxidized coenzyme F420-1
3    2.7.4.3  D-ribulose 5-phosphate       a secondary alcohol
4    3.1.2.3    2,3-dioxo-L-gulonate         a primary alcohol
5    2.7.2.3                L-iditol    D-ribulose 5-phosphate
```